# Oauth Client Credentials AccessToken where to store this token and access again

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, authorization, saml

I am using Spring Boot and I am using 3rd party API accessToken (by passing clientId and clientSecret).

```
public String getAccessToken(){
   return token;
}
```

Now, in all my services, to make use of 3rd party API, I need an accessToken for sure, so in every Service class, I am making call for getAccessToken() to get token and then making actual rest call.

By doing so above, its working. BUT somehow I am feeling like duplicate code ie., `getAccessToken()` everywhere in all service classes. Whats the best way to avoid duplicate? and most importantly I should never get inValid accessToken in any of my service classes

Comment: Its microservice architrecture ?

Comment: No...ours is normal Monolithic Architecture..

Answer (score 1):

when you are using 3rd party API,there are must a common code.

If you are using `RestTemplate`

add a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`

```
 RestTemplate template = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .additionalInterceptors((httpRequest, bytes, clientHttpRequestExecution) -> {
                    httpRequest.getHeaders().add("Authorization", getAccessToken());
                    return clientHttpRequestExecution.execute(httpRequest, bytes);
                })
                .build();
```

and then

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public yourResp yourFunc(String param){
  ... = restTemplate.getFor...

}
```